# Searching for how many times a word is occur consecutively in a string w/ Python (PSET6 CS50)

Tags: python

my goal is reading some strings (parts of DNA in this content) from a csv file, and then search another txt file for how many times those strings occur consecutively in those string but my current code creates an infinite loop(I did it that so way since I could not come up with a proper condition for while). Any help is appreciated thanks.

My idea was: Search the goal string if it is in, double its number if that's in too triple an increment the number until it is not in the `readed` anymore.

```
#Header line of csv : name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
# so checkstr = [AGATC,AATG,TATC] 
#Example of searched strings `GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACAAATCAAGCTGTCCGCTCGGCACGGCCTACACACGTCGTGTAACTACAACAGCTAGTTAATCTGGATATCACCATGACCGAATCATAGATTTCGCCTTAAGGAGCTTTACCATGGCTTGGGATCCAATACTAAGGGCTCGACCTAGGCGAATGAGTTTCAGGTTGGCAATCAGCAACGCTCGCCATCCGGACGACGGCTTACAGTTAGTAGCATAGTACGCGATTTTCGGGAAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCT`
```

For example should be able to find how many times consecutively `AGATC` occurs in that string and return that or record to memory.

```
checkstr = [] #global array that tells us what str to read
def readtxt(csvfile,seq):
    with open(f'{csvfile}','r') as p:#finding which str to read from header line of the csv
        header = csv.reader(p)
        for row in header:
            checkstr = row[1:]
            break
    with open(f'{seq}','r') as f:#searching the text for strs
        readed = f.read()
        for j in checkstr:
            n = 1
            jnew = n * j
            while True:
                if jnew in readed:
                    n += 1
                    print(f"{jnew} and {n}")
                    break
                else:
                    break
```

Comment: Please give examples of your input and output.

Comment: Edited the post please check it thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operates on the idea that splitting a string by a substring will return an empty string on consecutive substrings.  Such as:

```
s = 'abbcd'
s.split('b')
['a', '', 'cd']
```

In this case the number of consecutive `b` in `abbcd` is the count of empty strings plus 1 (2 in this case).

Expanding upon that we can use `itertools groupby` to count the number of times each group of text in the split string occurs, which as a result of the previous code means if we count the number of times `''` occurs in the list and add one we will get your answer.  The try/except statment is to handle instances where your substring is not in the string, and the resulting count is empty.

```
from itertools import groupby

checkstr = ['AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC']
s = 'GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACAAATCAAGCTGTCCGCTCGGCACGGCCTACACACGTCGTGTAACTACAACAGCTAGTTAATCTGGATATCACCATGACCGAATCATAGATTTCGCCTTAAGGAGCTTTACCATGGCTTGGGATCCAATACTAAGGGCTCGACCTAGGCGAATGAGTTTCAGGTTGGCAATCAGCAACGCTCGCCATCCGGACGACGGCTTACAGTTAGTAGCATAGTACGCGATTTTCGGGAAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCT'
for c in checkstr:
    groups = groupby(s.split(c))
    try:
        print(c,[sum(1 for _ in group)+1 for label, group in groups if label==''][0])
    except IndexError:
        print(c,0)
```

Output

```
AGATC 0
AATG 43
TATC 5
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution but I am a newbie to python can you explain your code or recommend some documentation, thank you for your time @Chris

Comment: Updated to add some clarification

Comment: Nice approach but it's got one issue which isn't apparent from the given example `checkstr`. If the groups of consecutive occurrences don't occur together (if that's possible), then the count is only of the first set of consecutive occurrences. Example: If you add two extra `AATG`s at the end of `checkstr`, then the AATG count stays at 43 but it should become 45. Think you'll need to store the groups separately and do the count afterwards, much like the ['store the results' example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in the docs.

Comment: `print(c,[sum(1 for _ in group)+1 for label, group in groups if label==''][0])` excuse me I googled this but could not found and this `print(c,0)` . I guess the first one includes some slicing but can not find more about it, and this usage of `print(c,0)` I don't know, please explain further if you don't mind.@Chris or @aneroid